# python regex get everything until specific strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
This is the most recent email of this thread

More text

From: a@a.com
Date: 13 August, 2018

More text...

From: a@a.com
Sent: Tuesday 23 July
To: b@b.com, c@c.com
Subject: Test
```

I need to extract everything until this string combination:

```
From: *
Sent: *
To: *
Subject: *
```

The `*` acts as a wildcard.

So my result should be:

```
This is the most recent email of this thread

More text

From: a@a.com
Date: 13 August, 2018

More text...
```

I want to filter this with a regular expression but I am not able to figure it out. Any pointers?

This is the regex pattern I tried in regex101 but it does not work in my python script for some reason:
`r"([\w\W\n]+?)\n((?:from:[^\n]+)\n+((?:\s*sent:[^\n]+)\n+(?:\s*to:[^\n]+)\n*(?:\s*cc:[^\n]+)*\n*(?:\s*bcc:[^\n]+)*\n*(?:\s*subject:[^\n]+)*))"`

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try ? What do you mean with `until` ?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jprLBn/4
I've tried this regular expression, but I am not able to make it work in my python script. I tried to use the multiline and global flag but not luck

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `re.findall` with a positive lookahead.  The approch here is to match everything from the start of the string up to, but not including, the block of text which should stop the match.

```
inp = """This is the most recent email of this thread

More text

From: a@a.com
Date: 13 August, 2018

More text...

From: a@a.com
Sent: Tuesday 23 July
To: b@b.com, c@c.com
Subject: Test"""

stop_text = """From: a@a.com
Sent: Tuesday 23 July
To: b@b.com, c@c.com
Subject: Test"""
matches = re.findall(r'^.*?(?=' + stop_text + ')', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['This is the most recent email of this thread\n\nMore text\n\nFrom: a@a.com\nDate: 13 August, 2018\n\nMore text...\n\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering [the example](https://regex101.com/r/jprLBn/4) you provided has the regex options `gim`, maybe you just need to enable the flag `re.IGNORECASE`?

```
text = """
This is the most recent email of this thread

More text

From: a@a.com
Date: 13 August, 2018

More text...

From: a@a.com
Sent: Tuesday 23 July
To: b@b.com, c@c.com
Subject: Test
"""
pattern = "([\w\W\n]+?)\n((?:from:[^\n]+)\n+((?:\s*sent:[^\n]+)\n+(?:\s*to:[^\n]+)\n*(?:\s*cc:[^\n]+)*\n*(?:\s*bcc:[^\n]+)*\n*(?:\s*subject:[^\n]+)*))"
print(re.findall(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE))
```

prints

```
[('\nThis is the most recent email of this thread\n\nMore text\n\nFrom: a@a.com\nDate: 13 August, 2018\n\nMore text...\n', 'From: a@a.com\nSent: Tuesday 23 July\nTo: b@b.com, c@c.com\nSubject: Test', 'Sent: Tuesday 23 July\nTo: b@b.com, c@c.com\nSubject: Test')]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it simple with grouping....

```
import re   
str = """This is the most recent email of this thread

More text

From: a@a.com
Date: 13 August, 2018

More text...

From: a@a.com
Sent: Tuesday 23 July
To: b@b.com, c@c.com
Subject: Test"""

x=re.match(r"""(.+?.+)
From:.+?
Sent:.+?
To: .+?,.+?
Subject:.+?.+""",str,flags=re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
print(x.groups())
```

group will give...the following result...

```
('This is the most recent email of this thread\n\nMore 
text\n\nFrom:a@a.com\nDate:13 August, 2018\n\nMore text...\n')
```